# How do I send my users to a new webpage that extends my current URL?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-development-server

I'm attempting to send my users to an entirely new webpage, but that extends my current URL.

For example, airbnb.com loads a completely different page compared to airbnb.com/become-a-host/room. One isn't "hidden" from the other, but they are treated as seperated webpages where you have to load everything going from one to the other. I want to do this for my own website, but I don't know how to do so.

I understand React Router, but I am not interested in "hiding" everything on one page and showing another. I am interested in rendering a completely new webpage that loads, but extends my current URL. Below is I am able to successfully send the user to the URL, but a new page isn't loaded.

[Text here](/new-webpage-link)

I want to load a new webpage, but the code above isn't doing so.

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for the server to serve different pages :)

Comment: `window.location.replace("long.url/new");`, as per 

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

Comment: How would I go about the server serving different pages? @JohnRuddell

Answer (score -1):

On a page, `website.ca`, execute the javascript (client side, so in `public/js/scripts.js` or similar):

```
window.location.replace("addition_to_url")
```

and that will redirect to the new page, with the addition added to the base url. ie, will take the user to `website.ca/addition_to_url`

source: w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

Comment: i supposed, this is not the scope of the question

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know the command, but again that still is just rendering everything that I had on my home page. Nothing is being loaded either.